# Change poll interval for Build Notification in TFS 2010

Tags: build, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to change the poll interval for the Build Notification tray application for TFS 2010?

Comment: You should consider marking Bertrand's post as the answer here.

Comment: Related question (but for refresh within VS IDE): http://stackoverflow.com/a/7829004/3063884    ... for anyone who comes here looking for the IDE refresh setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ironically, the code for the Build Notifcation tray application does support changing the poll interval by means of a parameterable constructor, but the root code which starts the polling off hard codes the value.

If you *really* want to change the poll interval, then you could theoretically create a replacement Main() procedure, and re write the launch of the form and polling timer in order to be able to pass in your own configurable poll interval, but I think that that would probably not be worth the time & investment.

EDIT: The upcoming 1.3.0 build of Jim Liddel's Team Build Screen on Codeplex now features support for TFS 2010, and also a desktop app rather than just a screensaver! This is far better than the team build screen. http://teambuildscreen.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you. This really sucks! The Build notification tray is very useful but works badly when doing frequent check-ins and fast CI builds.

Answer (score 13):

It case someone else searches for this;

The e-mail notificaiton delay does not affect the build notification tray

Check out this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukvsts/archive/2010/10/08/team-build-notification-polling-interval.aspx

Basically
There is a registry setting that controls this, and you can find it under:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\Build\BuildNotification\Subscriptions

Default is 2:30

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a quick Powershell one-liner:

`sp HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\build\BuildNotification\Subscriptions PollingInterval 00:00:05`

The "12.0" in the middle refers to VS 2013.  Change it to "10.0" for 2010, "11.0" for VS 2012, and "14.0" for Visual Studio "14".

Be aware that you have to restart the tool afterwards.  If you don't want to log out and back in, closing the tray app then running something like this from a Run prompt: `"%vs120comntools%..\ide\BuildNotificationApp.exe"` (with the double-quotes) ought to do the trick.

For those not so familiar with Powershell, "sp" is an alias for [Set-ItemProperty](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849844.aspx), which can work with many types of objects, including registry keys.