# Stop Refresh inside TFS Build window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

Is there a way to stop the constant refreshing inside Visual Studio when looking at a TFS Build?  Using VS 2010 SP1 and TFS 2010 SP1.  When watching a build in the Build window, the screen refreshes every 10 seconds or so.  Not a big deal except during every refresh the window resets to somewhere in the middle of the page if looking at the bottom of the build window (and it scrolls). So annoying.  I'd rather manually refresh to watch the build run instead of scrolling down to the bottom, then once getting to the bottom, scrolling again because the window reset.  Is there a way to turn off this automatic refresh?

Comment: I agree this scrolling to the middle of the log is VERY annoying. Deserves a Connect entry ...

Comment: You actually watch this build window? It's such a waste of time. You could do so many more productive tasks while waiting for the build. Personally I wait for notification of completed build once I check-in. Usually comes by email or instant messaging. If it contains red colors I review the log in a decent text editor where nothing scrolls while I read it. Notepad is a good one. And if the notification contains green colors, well, I am happy and enjoy my beer :-)

Comment: Perhaps watching was the wrong word.  More along the lines of seeing what custom task the build is executing currently.  By the time one scrolls down to the bottom, it auto-scrolls back to the middle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a way to make this stop. Add the following registry key

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\Build\UISettings with value name "ReportPollingInterval"

with a DWORD value (in ms) for the refresh interval. By default it refreshes every 10 seconds.

You will need to change "10.0" to your Visual Studio version (e.g. Visual Studio 2013 is "12.0", and Visual Studio 2015 is "14.0")

E.g. run this on your command line:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\Build\UISettings /v ReportPollingInterval /t REG_DWORD /d 1000000000
```

Comment: Thank you, although now that I know what to search on the blogs that I find are saying that it is stored in milliseconds.

Comment: Yep, sorry, it's ms. My bad :) Btw, we've addressed this issue in the next release of Visual Studio and TFS.

Comment: +1 @DuatLe thanks very much!  This bugs the heck out of me too.

Comment: +1 This also bugs me. While I rarely watch builds in progress, when I am investigating slow/unstable network file copying or other build strangeness or showing someone how a build works through each stage (so they get a better picture rather than "it's magic") this bug is indeed very annoying.

Comment: Setting it to zero disables refresh. Not sure if there's a way to manually refresh the page though

Comment: @DavidGardiner Apparently setting to zero causes the Build Request Dialog to break. Setting to a billion milliseconds is a safer way to "disable" refresh.

Comment: Is there a similar registry entry for SQL Server Profiler to disable window auto scroll by default? Although since this behavior is essentially the same between all these applications as it is in the Windows shell (i.e. command prompt), is there perhaps a global setting in the registry for everything Microsoft in Windows?
P.S. My use case for the build window is that the new stuff populating is so massive that it causes VS to be unresponsive for a second out of every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

ReportPollingInterval set to 0 means off.