# Activity log - duration time

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

My build contains 500+ projects with a lot of dependencies. It almost impossible to get the build duration values for the activities at the end of the build workflow.
Activity Log window is really slow. It takes 5 minutes to open the log and the window is refreshed after a few minutes after every click on the Activity Log scroll bar.

[image: My Activity Log window.]

I tried to open the build log using the web portal, but duration information is missing there.

Is it possible to get duration values in a different way?

Comment: I totally sympathize. Once it opens I do CTRL+A, CTRL+C & wait for ~10 minutes. Then I paste into Notepad++.

Comment: +1. I will accept it as a workaround if no other answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to view the build log in Visual Studio while the build is in progress, [making it not automatically restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828161/stop-refresh-inside-tfs-build-window-in-visual-studio/7829004#7829004) will probably give you a better experience.

Which verbosity do you set for you build? Is there a chance that you can lower your verbosity level to log less build information? Logging too much information was also an issue that we address in the next release.

If you want to get the duration of the build information nodes at the end of the build, you can do so by getting the IBuildDetail object that represents your build, querying the build information nodes of this IBuildDetail object, and computing the duration using the StartTime and FinishTime fields:

Built-in build information fields: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.common.informationfields.aspx